# Using Canvas client-side proxy to access Apex REST API from Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, api, canvas

Is it possible to use the [client-side proxy](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_app_xhr_intro.htm) provided by the Canvas SDK from a canvas app embedded within a Visualforce page to access an Apex REST endpoint?

We have a canvas app which calls an Apex REST endpoint

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax('/services/apexrest/myapp/myservice', {
   client: Sfdc._sr.client,
   success: myCallback
});
```

This works correctly when the canvas app is loaded from the chatter tab; both the chatter page and the API are on the same domain, `na7.salesforce.com`, for example.

But when the canvas app is embedded in a Visualforce page, it doesn't work because the Visualforce page is on `myapp.na7.visual.force.com`, and the client-side proxy sends the request to `na7.salesforce.com`, causing a cross-origin error.

Any suggestions on making this work?

It would be great if the client-side proxy transparently made use of ajax proxy on the Visualforce domain.

Comment: In case this helps, I did get a VF page to invoke a Canvas App that was just a VF page in another SF Org: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28524/canvas-publish-subscribe-and-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @BritishBoyinDC.  Your example works because it calls the Chatter API.  The Chatter API and REST APIs can be accessed from Visualforce domains (see http://bit.ly/1hldPOg), but Apex REST URLs can't.  You'll see that your request for the chatterFeedsUrl is sent to the visual.force.com domain rather than the salesforce.com domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have confirmed this is a problem. However there is a workaround

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax('/services/proxy',
   {   
       client : sr.client,
       method: 'GET',
       contentType: "application/json",
       headers : {
           "SalesforceProxy-Endpoint" : sr.client.instanceUrl + "/services/apexrest/Account/001i000000iLoMf",
           "Authorization" : "OAuth "  + sr.client.oauthToken,
           "Accept" : "application/json"
       },
       success : function(data) {
                alert("Status: " + data.status);
               }
    }
);
```